# Problems with basic python syntax for regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, match, bioinformatics

I'm studying for a bio-informatics exam but there are some things my professor did that i just don't understand. I've tried looking it up but can someone please explain this in a non-programmer language? I really have tried looking things up to understand but i'm just a bit clueless.My questions are about this;

```
import re
line = "Cats are smarter than dogs"
matchObj = re.match(r'(.*) are (.*?)*',line,re.M|re.I)

if matchObj:
  print("matchObj.group():",matchObj.group())
  print("matchObj.group():",matchObj.group(1))
  print("matchObj.group():",matchObj.group(2))
```

My questions:

- what does the (.*) do, i'm guessing you're trying to match 'cats' but then why don't you just type cats? I understand that . means 'any character' but i don't understand what * does
- What does the combination (.*?)*' do?
- What does re.M|re.I do?

Thanks so mutch! I'm starting to become a bit desperate. My mind just doesn't work in the right way to understand this kind of things i think.

Comment: Your question generalizes to "What are regular expressions" which is the kind of thing one takes a class on, not the kind of thing one answers in a couple paragraphs. The quick version is `(.*)` matches zero or more of any character and saves it in a group. `(.*?)*` does the same, but prefers fewer characters and the whole group is allowed to repeat zero or more times. `re.M|re.I` allows the regex to look at multiple lines and ignore case in matches.

Comment: There's a tutorial on regular expressions at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: If you don't know what * does, you need to read a basic regex tutorial. You won't get spoonfed here.

Comment: You will find [regex101](https://regex101.com) very interesting. You can interactively test regexes, and get the explanation as well!

Comment: note that `(.*?)` is silly at the end of an expression as it will only ever give you an empty string. Repeating it with `*` doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I did take a class on bio-informatics using python this semester but my professor was talking more about how great his business was than actually teaching bio-informatics. I really do try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll give you the first one, these are are actually as easy as regex you will ever see out there in the wild :)

`.` is any character

`*` is unlimited times

so...
`(.*)` is any character unlimited times

here is the link to python docs on regular expressions https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html... You can easily look up each character. Try one and post back here with your questions if you get stuck :)

Comment: Thanks! I know what . and * mean but i guess i should have asked why use it here in this way? Why not just look for the word cats?

Comment: Its the word in that spot of the sentence that your professor cares about... not the specific word "cats". So, if you had a hundred sentences the exact same except for that word where "cats" is located, then you would be able to parse all those sentences and get the word located in that spot. Regex is often about knowing _WHERE_ something will be, but not knowing _WHAT_ it will be. Does that help?

Comment: So the matchObj is not about finding that exact sentence in a database or something? He's just looking for every possible word that can be on that place in the sentence?

Comment: Correct, the example they gave you may be too trivial to really expose the reason why they were doing that... but you can try another sentence to prove it... `kittens are cuter than cats`. Any sentence that has a word followed by `are` will match this regex. Thats all they are trying to show you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answers! It makes a bit more sense now :)

Comment: Did this answer your question? Maybe you can accept my answer? :)

Comment: @Lily is that a no? :(

Comment: Sorry, i totally got distracted because of my exams. And i'm new here so i didn't know i had to accept an answer :) Sorry about that! And thanks so much again!